# Raspbian cannot display filenames with Eastern characters

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to host some files on my Raspberry Pi but it does not show filenames with Chinese and Japanese characters correctly. I plugged the USB stick on a Windows PC and an Android phone and they both can correctly display the file names.

The strange thing is if I use 7z to extract a file that contains files with Chinese characters in names, after the exaction these files can be displayed in the terminal fine. This leads me to suspect it has something to do with locale support in Raspbian. I tried to enable Chinese and Japanese locales in `raspi-config` and rebooted the Pi but it did not help.

Comment: You might want to log a bug here : https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs

Comment: Raspbian, like most modern Linux uses UTF-8 (although this can be changed) so ALL Unicode characters are supported. Certainly the filesystem uses Unicode. Inability to display is usually caused by a Font without glyphs for the characters.

Comment: Ah, let me see. When raspbian buster came out last June, I set my locale to Hong Kong Cantonese (YiuYu) and Chromium and MousePad could read/write/name Chinese files/directories without any problem.  But later releases did have teething problems. Recently I upgraded to buster 2020Feb13 Hongkong YiuYu everything work smoothly again. Cheers, TL方零壹.

Comment: Can you please add an example filename with Chinese characters to your question?